# How to manage with custom SegmentControllCell to tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, uisegmentedcontrol

I tried to manage from custom segment control cell into [ViewController's tableview cell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOHqE.jpg)

This is My custom segment control class:

```
protocol SegmentControllerCellDelegate: AnyObject {
func manageSegmentControl(cell: SegmentControllerCell)}

class SegmentControllerCell: UITableViewCell, ReusableView, NibLoadableView {

@IBOutlet weak var segmentController: UISegmentedControl!
weak var delegate: SegmentControllerCellDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setupUI()
    
}
 @IBAction func tappedSegmentControll(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    self.delegate?.manageSegmentControl(cell: self )
}}
```

And this is my view controller:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch BrandSection(rawValue: indexPath.section)! {
    case .profile:
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: BrandTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as? BrandTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.cellType = .brandPage
        return cell
    case .segment:
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: SegmentControllerCell.self), for: indexPath) as? SegmentControllerCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    case .products:
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: BrandProductionsCell.self), for: indexPath) as? BrandProductionsCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        return cell
    }
}

extension BrandProfileVC: SegmentControllerCellDelegate {
func manageSegmentControl(cell: SegmentControllerCell) {
   if cell.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
       self.brandTableView.reloadData()
       print("index 0")
   } else if cell.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
       self.brandTableView.reloadData()
       print("index 1")
   }
    
}}
```

I just want to show when I clicked segment control tab, different cell under the segment control.

Comment: this is ui design https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOHqE.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set the `cell.tag` as `indexPath.row` from `cellForRow` and then try to print the cell.tag inside the `manageSegmentControl` in your ViewController

This is the Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch BrandSection(rawValue: indexPath.section)! {
    case .profile:
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: BrandTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as? BrandTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.cellType = .brandPage
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
        
    case .segment:
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: SegmentControllerCell.self), for: indexPath) as? SegmentControllerCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
        
    case .products:
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: BrandProductionsCell.self), for: indexPath) as? BrandProductionsCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
        
    }
}

extension BrandProfileVC: SegmentControllerCellDelegate {
    func manageSegmentControl(cell: SegmentControllerCell) {
        if cell.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            self.brandTableView.reloadData()
            print(cell.tag)
        } else if cell.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            self.brandTableView.reloadData()
            print(cell.tag)
        }
    }
}
```